# how to add new element to Slivers Flutter with changing the UI?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

i need once the user click on send button. the text input field which he had add will be added to a list to be displayed inside the ListView. but the listView does NOT render the new element of the list. no change happen when the user click the send button!

**The Code Is:**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<MessageModel> message = [
      MessageModel(
        isMine: false,
        messageBody: "receiver_message".tr,
        time: "message_time".tr,
      ),
      MessageModel(
        isMine: true,
        messageBody: "message_sender_body".tr,
        time: "message_time".tr,
      ),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: message.length,
              // physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => MessageBody(
                isMine: message[index].isMine,
                messageBody: message[index].messageBody,
                time: message[index].time,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: 
       TextField(
          controller: message_controller,
          onChanged: (value) {},
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    var x=message_controller.text;
                    print("x $x");
                    message.add(
                      MessageModel(
                        isMine: true,
                        time: "message_time".tr,
                        messageBody: message_controller.text,
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                  icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward_rounded,
                ),
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you should initialize the list of Messages outside the build method because every time the view is recreated, it will re-initialize it and you would only have those values ​​that you are passing at the beginning, otherwise I recommend that you also declare the message_controller and You initialize it in the initState so that when you try to access it, it does not return null, here is an adaptation that I made based on your code so that you try to understand a little better, the add function is in the floating button, I hope you be helpful

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  late TextEditingController message_controller;
  List<String> message = ["aaa", "bbb"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    message_controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: message.length,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(message[index]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              var x = message_controller.text;
              message.add(x);
              print(message);
            });
          },
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: TextField(
              controller: message_controller,
              onChanged: (value) {
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    var x = message_controller.text;
                    print("x $x");
                    message.add(x);
                  }),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_rounded,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```